# Get IFeatureLayer from ILayer using ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, arcgis-engine, feature-layer

I try to select object from layer by name. I think i found sollution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141506/arcgis-engine-how-to-select-objects). 
First problem i got is that i use GroupLayer. So i made research how to get subLayer from GroupLayer. Sollution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570562/how-to-access-sublayer-of-a-basemap-in-arcobjects). Now i have a problem how to get IFeatureLayer if i already have ILayer from where i need to select object.

```
var mapControl = form.axMapControl2.ActiveView.FocusMap;

var basemapCompositeLayer = mapControl.Layer[0] as ICompositeLayer;
var basemapSubLayer = basemapCompositeLayer.Layer[0];
var featureLayer1 = basemapSubLayer as IFeatureLayer; // always NULL
```

Or this is because that Layer isn't Featured by default?

Comment: is layer 0 (the first or top layer) a composite layer (group layer)?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thanks for reply! basemapCompositeLayer is Composite Layer ("World Map") and basemapSubLayer is simple layer(" City(points)"). This map i get from ArcGIS Data and Maps, "World Map.mxd"

Comment: is the layer valid? basemapSubLayer.isValid() http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/componenthelp/esriCarto/ILayer_Valid.htm that looks like Java, does Java have typeof? In the map *world map.mxd* is the layer a WMS layer or is the data local?

Comment: yes, layer is valid. This is c#. Layer is local (this is base map-template from ArcGIS)

Comment: It doesn't look like c#. So the data is not referring to a WMS service on ESRI base maps... this is odd.

Comment: why it is strange? i get esri maps from distributive on local machine and use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14899/discussion-between-user2167382-and-michael-miles-stimson).

Comment: I removed your [tag:arcgis] tag because this Question is about ArcGIS Engine (and ArcObjects) rather than the ArcGIS Platform as a whole.  I also removed your [tag:ArcGIS-10.0] tag because version tags are used to indicate the latest version that you are seeing the problem in.  If you get a 10.1 solution that does not work at 10.0, and you need the latter too, then that is grounds to ask another Question specific to 10.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the conversation here is the code:

```
IMap mapControl = form.axMapControl2.ActiveView.FocusMap;
ICompositeLayer basemapCompositeLayer = (ICompositeLayer) mapControl.Layer[0];
ILayer basemapSubLayer = basemapCompositeLayer.Layer[0];
if (basemapSubLayer.Valid)
{
    if (basemapSubLayer is IFeatureLayer)
    {
        IFeatureLayer featureLayer1 = (IFeatureLayer) basemapSubLayer;
        // do your selection here
    }
    else if (basemapSubLayer is ICompositeLayer)
    {
        ILayer nextDown = (basemapSubLayer as ICompositeLayer).Layer[0];
        if (nextDown is IFeatureLayer)
        {
            IFeatureLayer featureLayer1 = (IFeatureLayer)nextDown;
            // do your selection here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post, you might serve: 
http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=159&f=1705&t=263219